# Why am i getting NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, interface

I have an interface

```
public interface IConfig
{
    string name { get; set; }
    string address { get; set; }
    int phone { get; set; }

    List<string> children { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my config file that has only three app settings not four like i have in interface.

```
<add key="name" value="abc" />
<add key="address" value="100 Norin Street" />
<add key="phone" value="709-111-111111" />
```

Now on startup I am using DictionaryAdapterFactory to fillin the app.config file values. I am successfully getting values of app.config here.

```
private readonly IConfig _config;
private readonly DictionaryAdapterFactory _factory;
_factory = new DictionaryAdapterFactory();
_config = _config.GetAdapter<IConfig>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);
```

now at run time I need to fill in the value of children which is List type. But i am getting null exception. Why?

```
//loop
_config.children.Add(item.values);
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

missing somewhere a list initialization ?

```
_config.children = new List<string>()
```

Comment: I tried it but then i get this error. {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'."}

Comment: show more code, your message makes not that much sense for me

Comment: @user1327064 which line of code threw that "unable to cast" exception?

Comment: Guys..I think somehow DictionaryAdapterFactory is not letting me do it.

Comment: @phoog This is line of code threw the error _config.children.Add(item.values);

Comment: @user1327064 what is the type of `item.values`?

Comment: var item =  children.Split(new[] { ','}; //then  initialization _config.children = new List<string>(); //then loop and in loop _config.children.Add(item.values);

Comment: @phoog. Try this above scenario I explained in my question. App.config file does not have children key. then i filled in _config using dictionaryadapter and the initialized children and...so on... Thanks for your interest though

Comment: @user1327064 I'm sorry, it's difficult to read code in a comment.  In addition, the code doesn't seem to compile.  Is the children in `children.Split` a string?  If so, then `item` will be an array of strings; it doesn't have a `.values` property.  Please edit your question or post a new question showing the entire method that's raising the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be like following?

```
_config.children.AddRange(item.values);
```

Of course, the initialization is also required.

```
_config.children = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Defined 'Phone' as int in interface while phone value in AppSettings is not cast-able to int. change it to string:

```
  string phone { get; set; }
```